# Implementing HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, highcharts

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-eTP5pEh4kFs/T7BoGRdwlmI/AAAAAAAAAHc/AQzgo6qkBkQ/w1257-h669-k/graph.JPG

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column',
            margin: [ 50, 50, 100, 80]
        },
        title: {
            text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2008'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Tokyo',
                'Jakarta',
                'New York',
                'Seoul',
                'Manila',
                'Mumbai',
                'Sao Paulo',
                'Mexico City',
                'Dehli',
                'Osaka',
                'Cairo',
                'Kolkata',
                'Los Angeles',
                'Shanghai',
                'Moscow',
                'Beijing',
                'Buenos Aires',
                'Guangzhou',
                'Shenzhen',
                'Istanbul'
            ],
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                align: 'right',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    'Population in 2008: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1) +
                    ' millions';
            }
        },
            series: [{
            name: 'Population',
            data: [34.4, 21.8, 20.1, 20, 19.6, 19.5, 19.1, 18.4, 18,
                17.3, 16.8, 15, 14.7, 14.5, 13.3, 12.8, 12.4, 11.8,
                11.7, 11.2],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                x: -3,
                y: 10,
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.y;
                },
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

});

[Help]
 How could I implement this using HighCharts a js plugin..? Any comment, advices would be very much appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that what you want is multiple series. So, let's say you want "Population (total)", "Population (male)", and "Population (female)" you just add more series to the array.

Please ignore the fact that my "male + female = total" numbers don't add up.

Also the resulting chart is very busy, but I'll leave that to you. Usually when creating a bar chart with multiple series, you'll want to keep the number of bars fairly small. Otherwise it might be better to use a line chart or area chart or whichever fits your need (sorry I don't read Japanese very well).

But this point you in the direction you want to go.

```
$(function () {
  var chart;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column',
        margin: [ 50, 50, 100, 80]
    },
    title: {
        text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2008'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Tokyo',
            'Jakarta',
            'New York',
            'Seoul',
            'Manila',
            'Mumbai',
            'Sao Paulo',
            'Mexico City',
            'Dehli',
            'Osaka',
            'Cairo',
            'Kolkata',
            'Los Angeles',
            'Shanghai',
            'Moscow',
            'Beijing',
            'Buenos Aires',
            'Guangzhou',
            'Shenzhen',
            'Istanbul'
        ],
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            align: 'right',
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                'Population in 2008: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1) +
                ' millions';
        }
    },
        series: [{
        name: 'Population',
        data: [34.4, 21.8, 20.1, 20, 19.6, 19.5, 19.1, 18.4, 18,
            17.3, 16.8, 15, 14.7, 14.5, 13.3, 12.8, 12.4, 11.8,
            11.7, 11.2],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            x: -3,
            y: 10,
            formatter: function() {
                return this.y;
            },
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Male',
        data: [34.4, 21.8, 20.1, 20, 19.6, 19.5, 19.1, 18.4, 18,
            17.3, 16.8, 15, 14.7, 14.5, 13.3, 12.8, 12.4, 11.8,
            11.7, 11.2],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            x: -3,
            y: 10,
            formatter: function() {
                return this.y;
            },
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Female',
        data: [34.4, 21.8, 20.1, 20, 19.6, 19.5, 19.1, 18.4, 18,
            17.3, 16.8, 15, 14.7, 14.5, 13.3, 12.8, 12.4, 11.8,
            11.7, 11.2],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            x: -3,
            y: 10,
            formatter: function() {
                return this.y;
            },
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
          }
        }
      }]
    });
  });
});
```